# Regex to detect phone number starting with *

Tags: regex

How to detect phone number using Regex, I am using this expression:

```
(((\d)(-)?)+){7,15}
```

It's working good, but i need this expression to detect also phone number starting with * ?

Comment: escape the wildcard character like this :`\*` or [*]

Comment: `it's working good` really? is this a phone-num? `5-5-5-5-5-5-5-`

Comment: Or even this one: `1-2-31-2-31-2-31-2-31-2-31-2-31-2-31-2-31-2-31-2-31-2-3`

Answer (score 0):

```
\*(((\d)(-)?)+){7,15}
```

That regex should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
Expression  : ^\(\d{3}\) ?\d{3}( |-)?\d{4}|^\d{3}( |-)?\d{3}( |-)?\d{4}
```

Matches : (658)154-1122 | 6581541122 | 658-154-1122

Non-Matches : (658 154 1122 | 759-1245 | 875 (489 1568)

Comment: What question are you answering?

Answer (score 0):

```
(((\d)(-)?)+){7,15}|^\*\d{4}$
```

Updated ans.

This will detect regular ph number without `*` and phone number starting with `*` followed by exactly 4 digits.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/5